# MYSQL - How to find which hour has the most number of searches

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with using datetime values. I want to find which hour has the most number of searches
Here is some sample data

```
 Srch_id         dttime
  1             2013-04-04 08:32:15
  1             2013-04-04 08:32:15
  1             2013-04-04 08:32:15
  1             2013-04-04 08:32:15
  2             2012-12-31 08:59:22
  2             2012-12-31 08:59:22
  2             2012-12-31 08:59:22
  3             2013-12-31 09:22:22
  3             2013-12-31 09:22:22
```

This is the result I want

```
  Searches      HourofSearch
  7             08
```

select srch_id, (hour(dttime) from table... Not sure where to go from here

Comment: Not enough time to give you a complete solution, but try substrings and grouping like this: `search count(*) from table group by substring(dttime, 11, 13)` or similar. Google grouping and substrings. Or, as an alternative, perhaps a better one, google for datetime functions to extract the hour from dttime. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the hour, order by the count for each and take the first record only

```
select hour(dttime) as HourofSearch, count(*) as Searches
from your_table
group by hour(dttime)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c33a5/9) is a working example.

Comment: Well, unless there's a tie

Comment: Great. That makes sense. Thanks so much!